# Understanding the impact of var and val with respect to getters and setters of a property

Tags: kotlin, oop

Let's say I have a Kotlin class `Dog` with two properties `weight` and `weightInKgs`

```
class Dog(val weight: Double) {  
    // property without initializing works. Why?
    val weightinKgs: Double
    get() = weight/ 2.2;
}
```

The above code runs without errors. I know that every property in Kotlin must be initialized so why does defining a getter without initializing the property work? Secondly, when `val` is changed to `var` for `weightInKgs`, it produces an error asking for initialization. How does changing it to `var` break the code?

```
class Dog(val weight: Double) {
    // well its doesn't work now. 
    var weightinKgs: Double
        get() = weight/ 2.2;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every property *with a backing field* must be initialized. A property has a backing field if any of the following is true:

- You initialize the backing field at the declaration site using `=`.
- It has a custom getter or setter that references `field`.
- It uses the implicit getter or setter, which implicitly uses `field`.

Otherwise, it does not have a backing field.

If there is no backing field used by the getter and/or setter, there is no need to initialize one. Your first code block has a custom getter that doesn't use `field`.

In your second code block, you have a `var` and it's using the implicit setter, which uses the backing field, so the backing field must be initialized.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not obvious, `get()` is a function that calculates a value (`weight / 2.2`) every time you call it. It's basically the equivalent to this

```
fun getWeightInKgs(): Double {
    return weight / 2.2
}
```

So that's why it doesn't have a backing field, it's not actually storing a value. But Kotlin presents these kinds of `getX()` functions (and `set`, `is` etc) as properties, and encourages you to use property access syntax, so `dog.weightInKgs` instead of `dog.getWeightInKgs()`. Kinda hiding the specific implementation details

If you didn't want to calculate the weight every time, and just wanted to do it once, then you'd just do

```
val weightInKgs = weight / 2.2
```

and then it *would* have a backing field, because that value has to be stored somewhere. You could also have a getter function that refers to a private `val` or `var` and returns the value of that, instead of [giving the property itself a backing field](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#backing-fields), but if you ever need to do that kind of thing you'll probably understand why you would! That's usually for when your getter and/or setter is doing something a bit more complicated than just hiding or validating an internal data value